# Take a screenshot of background app without launching it

Tags: screen-recording, screenshot, screen-sharing

I'm running Android 13 on a Samsung device. I have an app that runs in the background. I want to be able to either:

1. take a screenshot of the app's screen without launching it, i.e. while it's still in the background or
2. broadcast or mirror that particular app's screen to a webpage / url or
3. spy on / monitor that app's screen without launching it

Basically I want to obtain the information on the screen of the app without triggering it, because when I do, I will then be forced to take action on the information that's showing, but sometimes it is best to ignore it. Is there an app or work around that can allow me to do this?